# Create a column for cumulative sum for each string value in a column pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have the following pandas dataframe

```
import pandas as pd
import random

random.seed(42)

pd.DataFrame({'index': list(range(0,10)),
         'cluster': [random.choice(['S',  'C', ]) for l in range(0,10)]})


    index   cluster
0   0   S
1   1   S
2   2   C
3   3   S
4   4   S
5   5   S
6   6   S
7   7   S
8   8   C
9   9   S
```

I would like to create 5 new columns, one for each unique value of the `cluster` column, which will be the cumulative sum of appearances of each value.

The output pandas dataframe should look like this :

```
pd.DataFrame({'index': list(range(0,10)),
             'cluster': [random.choice(['S',  'C', ]) for l in range(0,10)],
             'cumulative_S': [1,2,2,3,4,5,6,7,7,8],
             'cumulative_C': [0,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,2,2]})

index   cluster cumulative_S    cumulative_C
0   0   S   1   0
1   1   S   2   0
2   2   C   2   1
3   3   S   3   1
4   4   S   4   1
5   5   S   5   1
6   6   S   6   1
7   7   S   7   1
8   8   C   7   2
9   9   S   8   2
```

How can I achieve that ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Code**

`df` is your input dataframe

```
tmp = (pd.get_dummies(df['cluster'])
       .cumsum()[df['cluster'].unique()]
       .add_prefix('cumulative_')
)
out = pd.concat([df, tmp],axis=1)
```

out

```
   index cluster  cumulative_S  cumulative_C
0      0       S             1             0
1      1       S             2             0
2      2       C             2             1
3      3       S             3             1
4      4       S             4             1
5      5       S             5             1
6      6       S             6             1
7      7       S             7             1
8      8       C             7             2
9      9       S             8             2
```

Answer (score 3):

Here's one way to do it:

- Convert 'cluster' column into indicator variables and compute the cumulative sum
- Rename the columns as required
- Concatenate the cumulative counts with the original DataFrame

```
cum_counts = pd.get_dummies(df['cluster']).cumsum()
cum_counts = cum_counts.rename(columns=lambda x: f'cumulative_{x}')
df_final = pd.concat([df, cum_counts], axis=1)
```

And here's the output of your example:

```
   index cluster  cumulative_C  cumulative_S
0      0       S             0             1
1      1       S             0             2
2      2       C             1             2
3      3       S             1             3
4      4       S             1             4
5      5       S             1             5
6      6       S             1             6
7      7       S             1             7
8      8       C             2             7
9      9       S             2             8
```

Answer (score 2):

Another version:

```py
x = df.join(pd.crosstab(df.index, df["cluster"]).cumsum().add_prefix("cumulative_"))

print(x)
```

Prints:

```
   index cluster  cumulative_C  cumulative_S
0      0       S             0             1
1      1       S             0             2
2      2       C             1             2
3      3       S             1             3
4      4       S             1             4
5      5       S             1             5
6      6       S             1             6
7      7       S             1             7
8      8       C             2             7
9      9       S             2             8
```

Comment: good day dear Andrej - awesome: you offer a great approach - and your ideas are just great - (as usually : i have seen a whole lot of great solutions you provided. ) but this does not work for me. I am willing to get the data out of clutch.co - with as most as we can get ouf of the pages. But i tried several steps and nothing worked correct for me. Perhalps you can provied a  approach that works. Loook forward to hear from you Regards. btw: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77978889/ love to hear from you ... regards